# When failed to load static files from Google CDN - it's impossible to report bugs on meta

Tags: bug, captcha

I had a problem with Google CDN, which caused both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow  to show the following error:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Got the following error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at stub.en.js?v=d72e0d87a82d:1
```

For the file

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=d72e0d87a82d
```

Problem was that when I tried to ask a question in meta I got the following:

[image]

Which was a bit hard to solve :)

Comment: this is [tag:status-bydesign] if the page didn't get required resources, it will misbehave

Comment: @i-- I understand the error (at the beginning), keep read the rest of my question...

Comment: Since jQuery file is failed to load, it can't render the things and process form correctly

Comment: It might not be a good idea to rely on jquery in order to use recaptcha (in case both come from the same cdn), however I don't think this is the case...

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue here, it something fails to load of course the page won't display correctly. That's like expecting a car to run without an engine.

Comment: The `recaptcha` code can run perfectly without jquery...

Comment: I think jQuery is used by SO to initiate the captcha

Comment: That robot on the right...Since when did ASIMO have Johnny Fives head? umm....